# Laravel 7.28.1 Missing required parameters for [Route: komisis.destroy] [URI: komisis/{komisi}]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, infyom

Hi what is the problem in my routing please help me
this is my Table_blade

```
        @foreach($komisis as $komisi)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $komisi->nomor  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $komisi->komisi }}</td>
                <td>
                    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['komisis.destroy', $komisi->nomor], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <a href="{{ route('komisis.show', [$komisi->nomor]) }}" class='btn btn-ghost-success'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                        <a href="{{ route('komisis.edit', [$komisi->nomor]) }}" class='btn btn-ghost-info'><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                        {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-ghost-danger', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')"]) !!}
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

this is my routing

```
Route::resource('komisis', 'komisiController');
```

this is my controller

```
<?php



{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
      
    
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $komisi = $this->komisiRepository->find($id);

        if (empty($komisi)) {
            Flash::error('Komisi not found');

            return redirect(route('komisis.index'));
        }

        $this->komisiRepository->delete($id);

        Flash::success('Komisi deleted successfully.');

        return redirect(route('komisis.index'));
    }
}
```

and this is my model

so i have been trying to use infyom to do crud to my project i do clean install
and try to connect to mssql

but it raise routing issues

what is the problem with the code

or
what have i forgot

i tried to only show too but it didn't work

please help
thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you adjust `['komisis.destroy', $komisi->nomor]` to `['komisis.destroy', 'komisi' => $komisi->nomor]` and see if that helps?

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me
but it is still now working
i am trying to connect the code with mssql is it compatible?
should i migrate first? or anything that i missed

Comment: does `$komisi->nomor` actually have a value in every record?

Comment: in mssql it is auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as:

```
 @foreach($komisis as $komisi)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $komisi->nomor  }}</td>
        <td>{{ $komisi->komisi }}</td>
            <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['komisis.destroy',  'id' => $komisi->nomor], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                <div class='btn-group'>
                    <a href="{{ route('komisis.show', [$komisi->nomor]) }}" class='btn btn-ghost-success'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                    <a href="{{ route('komisis.edit', [$komisi->nomor]) }}" class='btn btn-ghost-info'><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                    {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-ghost-danger', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')"]) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply
but it is still not working

about the table 
in my sql there are no deleted_at or created_at or other olequent

should i make it first? or migrate first?
is it compatible with mssql?

Comment: i mean not mysql but MSsql

Answer (score 0):

After I change my primary key kolom
it works

add this configuration to your
model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'yourpkcolumn';
```

thanks for all your help